# How to Show Outlook WebAddin Task Pane inside Calendar window

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I am developing webAddin for showing Task pane inside the Calander window not Outlook main window (explorer ) .
Is there any setting in manifest file to achieve the same ?

Comment: Currently the feature: Show Outlook Add-in Taskpane in calendar view, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform